# Some Installing Errors while building owncloud client

Tags: ubuntu, apt, compiling, dependencies

I want to develop my OwnCloud client so I cloned a client of OwnCloud repository from GitHub and I read this [documentation](https://doc.owncloud.org/desktop/latest/building.html). Firstly, I want to say my system property. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (64 bit) so I tried Ubuntu steps in this documentation.

I tried steps at the below.

I added source link to source list of system.

```
echo 'deb-src http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_18.04/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/owncloud-client.list
```

Then, I updated my system.

```
apt-get update;
```

Lastly, I tried build-dep function. Because, OwnCloud documentation says this command.

```
 apt-get build-dep owncloud-client
```

First two steps worked successfully but at last step, I am getting an error.

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 builddeps:owncloud-client : Depends: ocqt5101-qt5-qmake but it is not installable
                             Depends: ocqt5101-qttools5-dev-tools but it is not installable
                             Depends: ocqt5101-qtbase5-dev but it is not installable
                             Depends: ocqt5101-qt5keychain-dev (>= 0.7.0) but it is not installable
                             Depends: ocqt5101-libqt5webkit5-dev (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
                             Depends: ocqt5101-qtsvg5 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to compile this dependencies manually like that

```
sudo apt-get build-dep ocqt5101-qt5-qmake
```

but it is not working. I am getting same result.

How can I build this sources?

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference building the owncloud client with

1. `apt-get build-dep`
2. or cloning from github.com and compiling the source code (with cmake)

As a developer you might [prefer 2.](https://doc.owncloud.org/desktop/latest/building.html#generic-build-instructions).

For 1.:

You can download the needed binaries `dep` files from http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_18.04/amd64

and install them with dpkg. (ie. `dpkg -i ocqt5101-qt5-qmake_5.10.1-1+1.1_amd64.deb` or `dpkg -i *.deb` for all downloaded deb files in pwd)

QT5 is the application framework. It's not neccessary to compile that from source.

For 2. you can use the debs named above or download directly from the [qt website](https://www.qt.io/download).

make sure to install the needed build tools like

`apt-get install build-essential`

good luck!